what is the meaning of “One-sample test.”？The following is clearly a two-sample test for wilcox.test
The code that inspired this question can be found here and below:
require(graphics)
## One-sample test.
## Hollander & Wolfe (1973), 29f.
## Hamilton depression scale factor measurements in 9 patients with
##  mixed anxiety and depression, taken at the first (x) and second
##  (y) visit after initiation of a therapy (administration of a
##  tranquilizer).
x <- c(1.83,  0.50,  1.62,  2.48, 1.68, 1.88, 1.55, 3.06, 1.30)
y <- c(0.878, 0.647, 0.598, 2.05, 1.06, 1.29, 1.06, 3.14, 1.29)
wilcox.test(x, y, paired = TRUE, alternative = "greater")
wilcox.test(y - x, alternative = "less")    # The same.
wilcox.test(y - x, alternative = "less",
            exact = FALSE, correct = FALSE) # H&W large sample
                                            # approximation

What is the meaning of “One-sample test.”? The following is clearly a two-sample test.

What I can think of, is that this is called a "one sample test", because it is looking at the differences between x and y (e.g. see the second wilcox.test call). So it's a one-sample test of differences.

I'm not entirely sure what led you to that conclusion. The $x$ and $y$ variables are supposed to represent scores for the same group tested multiple times (admittedly, the label should be something more like "Time 1" and "Time 2"). The description even notes this:

Hamilton depression scale factor measurements in 9 patients with mixed anxiety and depression, taken at the first (x) and second (y) visit after initiation of a therapy (administration of a tranquilizer).

The tests directly following perform a one-sample paired test accordingly.

This is a prefect reply in read the next line. +1.

With reference to One Sample T Test, I think this is a "one sample test."https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/one-sample-t-test/

Still, both only use one sample (the group under investigation) to answer the question. If we were comparing two different groups against each other, then this would be a different perspective.

“one sample” means “Same set of object of study”？

wilcox.test(x, y, paired = TRUE, alternative = "greater")
is same as
wilcox.test(y - x, mu = 0, alternative = "less")
so,it is a "one sample test"

Yes, you are correct with both statements. Since we only have one sample in each case (here the same 9 subjects), it wouldn't make sense to call it a two-sample approach.
